# What happened to the context menu in my console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Was creating a simple console application to do some prototyping and was shocked to see that the right-click/context menu is missing from a standard .NET console app!

I'm unable to find any information about this, and intellisense isn't helping.

So what happened to it?  Can I get it back?  And if not, how can I configure my console application to treat ctrl-c/ctrl-v as standard?

Comment: I've never had c-c/c-v work in the console...instead I've always used Select/mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context menu doesn't show up when you right click on the console app body (not the title bar) when VS debugger is attached.

Answer (score 4):

This is a windows console settings thing. Right click on the task bar of the app, click Properties and check / uncheck quick edit mode.

Also there is no way to get Ctr-C Ctrl-V working in console apps (as far as I know)

Comment: +1 What a nice feature! It should be on by default! Didn't know about that.

Comment: Just a notice to other users Ctr-C / Ctrl-V do not work in Console At All you cant even do them in CMD!